# Expected Behavior for Clicking on Back Button After Login

Tags: angular, web

Currently facing an issue where after a user logs in to my Angular application and then clicks on the back button, they are presented with a broken page and infinite spinner (loading indicator).

I saw this issue and am now curious as to what the expected action should be for this scenario?

Should a user even be allowed to click after landing on the home page after logging in? Should we re-direct them back to the main page if we see that they are already logged in?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the console error?

Comment: you can simply check on login component constructor that user loggedin or not if yes then redirect to main page or you can use auth guard feature of angular.

Answer (score 0):

"Should we re-direct them back to the main page if we see that they are already logged in?"

I always do this, it seems safe and we never got any bug concerning login.